# Is a VSTO application considered a macro as far as office is concerned?

Tags: macros, ms-word, vsto

Is a VSTO application considered a macro as far as office is concerned? In other words, will macro sensitive antivirus software give me trouble? And will the Word trust Center settings need to be changed to allow macros?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VSTO app is totally different from a VBA macro, and should not trigger any macro-related warnings. A macro is a script attached to the document; simply opening an office document could trigger some potentially harmful VBA code, without warning to the user. By contrast, a VSTO app is a .NET app which needs to be explicitly installed and accepted by the user on his machine.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, that helps clarify it for me.

Comment: Glad it helped. Interestingly, what your question highlights at is that VSTO is fundamentally much safer than VBA - but the flipside is that deploying a VSTO customization is much more complicated than distributing a VBA macro - something a lot of people used to the simplicity of VBA complain about... As usual, no silver bullet!

Answer (score 1):

Mathias gave us an excellent answer. I totally agree with that. But I also just want to add a little bit more things about VSTO here based on some of my own experiences.

VSTO add-in is basically an application-level extension for MS Office. It requires .NET framework & VSTO runtime to be installed on the target machine in order to run correctly (In some case, PIA is needed as well). VSTO runtime is not too good in terms of compatibility, and greatly dependent on Office version. For example, Office 2003 doesn't work with VSTO 4.

Using VSTO opens opportunity for .net programmers who'd like to create MS Office based applications. It certainly is more powerful than what VBA can offer.

But the downside of any VSTO application is the challenges in deployment. Although ClickOnce approach is meant to make the whole deployment a bit easier, the process is still not as easy as falling off a log, especially for deployment using Windows Installer approach. Special registry keys, permissions, and all that just give you a headache from time to time. Also API is not documented very well, code examples aren't enough either... Well, anyway, I think VSTO still has its potentials and hopefully Microsoft will provide better support in the near future and more people join community of VSTO development.